# Performing Feynman parameter integral

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, integration

How can I evaluate this integral?$$\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{z}{1-z}\delta(x+y+z-1)dxdydz$$ I am getting $2\ln2-1$, but the answer should be $\frac12$.

Comment: Can you properly typeset the integral?  Your notation is not understandable.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. I've formatted your integral with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020). Please edit your question to show how you got your answer; maybe we can spot a small error which, when fixed, gets $\frac12$ instead.

Comment: You need to take into account the region of integration. The delta function can only set $z=1-x-y$ in the region where $0<x+y<1$, which is a triangular region in x and y.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I evaluate this integral?$$\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{z}{1-z}\delta(x+y+z-1)dxdydz$$ I am getting $2\ln2-1$, but the answer should be $\frac12$.

You need to take into account the region of integration. The delta function can only set $z=1-x-y$ in the region where $1-x-y$ is between $0$ and $1$.

This means you need $0<1-x-y<1$, which means that the only non-zero contribution in $x$ and $y$ comes from the region where  $0<x+y<1$, which is a triangular region in $x$ and $y$.

Thus, after the $z$ integration you should end up with:
$$
I = \int_0^1 dx \int_0^{1-x} dy \left(\frac{1}{x+y}-1\right)\;.
$$

I will let you take it from here.